# Cannot declare class mPDF, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, class, mpdf

I'm trying to include a library/plugin named mPDF.  Here is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function cert() {
        require_once base_path('App/Http/Controllers/mpdf/mpdf.php');
        $mpdf=new mpdf\mPDF();
        return true;
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot declare class mPDF, because the name is already in use

When I comment out the require_once line, I get:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\mpdf\mPDF' not found

mpdf.php has a class named mPDF. It only has one class with this name.  This class appears nowhere else in my project. No other classes have the same name.

Comment: Add namespace in your mPDF class  like this. `namespace App\Http\Controllers\mpdf;`

Comment: Class files should also be named with capital letters. This could give you headaches if you deploy your code on a server running OS with case sensitive file systems

Comment: any reason to not install this with composer, which would autoload this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the name space of your 
**App/Http/Controllers/mpdf/mpdf.php** file
put something on top of the file like :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\MyPDF;
```

After defining name space in your library class file **App/Http/Controllers/mpdf/mpdf.php** file, include that class into your controller as

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\MyPDF\mPDF;
class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function cert() {
        //require_once base_path('App/Http/Controllers/mpdf/mpdf.php');
        $mpdf=new mPDF();
        return true;
  }
}
```

I would recommend not to create library class as a controller or inside controller directory, create library classes in /app/ directory and provide your own namespace.

Actually Namespaces are same as package name in JAVA, you just need to define proper name space for your class and include your class without any conflict if there are same classes. Same class name and different name space will not cause conflict.

Comment: This worked, though I had to leave the require_once in or I would still get the "not found" error.

Comment: You dont need require_once because use statement and namespace will do that.

Comment: Without it I still get "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MyPDF\mPDF' not found"
My code is identical (copy-pasted) to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Within `App/Http/Controllers/mpdf/mpdf.php` file make sure you have the namespace.

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\mpdf;`

Then change your code to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function cert() {
        $mpdf=new mpdf\mPDF();
        return true;
  }

}
```

The use `use App\Http\Controllers`'s within the above code are not required as you're already in the namespace.